# What do you use instead of ENUM in doctrine2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

What do you use instead of ENUM in Doctrine2? smallint? I thought of using varchar, or explicitly define char, but this may not be very effective when it comes to indexes, or am I wrong?

Comment: I think you need this cookbook (taken from the official Doctrine documentation): http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/cookbook/mysql-enums.html
It's exactly your problem and it gives 2 solutions. Just choose yours.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I usually work with integers mapped to class constants, like

```
class MyEntity {
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
    const STATUS_REFUSE = 2;

    protected $status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
}
```

That works quite fine and makes it even easier to work with what you would call ENUMS in an IDE.

You can also [use an enumerable type as described by the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html), but that means you will have to define one custom type per enum column. That's a lot of work with no real benefit.

You may also want to know [why you shouldn't really use enums](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/).

Comment: one issue -- when dealing with values outside of `MyEntity`, you have to either re-encode constants, or use `0, 1, 2`. 

i.e. `$entity->setStatus(STATUS_ACTIVE);  //does not work outside of MyEntity`

Comment: @Dennis the usage would be `$entity->setStatus(MyEntity::STATUS_ACTIVE);`

Comment: Doesn't this tightly couple the classes that use `MyEntity` to the specific implementation? Would it be better to define these constants in a `MyEntityInterface` that `MyEntity` then implements?

Comment: @Alex that's a great question and I think you're right, it does create some extra coupling that smells a bit. What about something like `$entity->deactivate()` etc that hides the implementation of the constants?

Comment: Personally I don't think Doctrine is the problem. The problem is there's no enum type in PHP and therefore we could get unintended values in the database. If we could simply make sure the setter & getter would always use the correct values, it would be great. Closest I've been able to come is the SplEnum type.. https://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php

Answer (score 14):

**Postgres, Symfony, ORM, Doctrine...**

1. Postgres: Define new type enum (pgAdmin)

   ```sql
   CREATE TYPE new_enum AS ENUM ('sad', 'ok', 'happy');
   ```
2. In Entity

   ```
   @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", columnDefinition="new_enum", 
   nullable=true)
   ```
3. In config.yml

   ```yaml
   mapping_types:
       new_enum: string
   ```

   ```yaml
   # Doctrine Configuration
   doctrine:
       dbal:
           driver:   "%database_driver%"
           host:     "%database_host%"
           port:     "%database_port%"
           dbname:   "%database_name%"
           user:     "%database_user%"
           password: "%database_password%"
           charset:  UTF8
           mapping_types:
               new_enum: string # <=======
   ```

Answer (score 7):

If you want MySQL ENUMs using MySQL and Symfony, you can now use an easy way for that without any dependencies

## use a base class for all enums:

```
<?php

namespace App\Enum;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

abstract class EnumType extends Type
{
    protected $name;
    protected $values = [];

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $values = array_map(function($val) { return "'".$val."'"; }, $this->values);

        return "ENUM(".implode(", ", $values).")";
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (!in_array($value, $this->values)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid '".$this->name."' value.");
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

## extend it for your special case:

```
namespace App\Enum;

 class UploadFileStatusType extends EnumType
{
     const OPEN = 'open';
     const DONE = 'done';
     const ERROR = 'error';

     protected $name = self::class;

     protected $values = [
         self::OPEN => self::OPEN ,
         self::DONE => self::DONE,
         self::ERROR => self::ERROR,
     ];

}
```

## add it to your dcotrine.yml config file:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            UploadFileStatusType: App\Enum\UploadFileStatusType
```

## use it in your entity file as doctrine column doc type:

```
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="UploadFileStatusType")
     */
    protected $status;
}
```

## And you will end up with a clean MySQL ENUM type for column status:

```
enum('open', 'done', 'error')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [fre5h/DoctrineEnumBundle](https://github.com/fre5h/DoctrineEnumBundle) for doctrine when using symfony:

**Example of using**

Create a class for new ENUM type BasketballPositionType:

```
<?php
namespace App\DBAL\Types;

use Fresh\DoctrineEnumBundle\DBAL\Types\AbstractEnumType;

final class BasketballPositionType extends AbstractEnumType
{
    public const POINT_GUARD = 'PG';
    public const SHOOTING_GUARD = 'SG';
    public const SMALL_FORWARD = 'SF';
    public const POWER_FORWARD = 'PF';
    public const CENTER = 'C';

    protected static $choices = [
        self::POINT_GUARD => 'Point Guard',
        self::SHOOTING_GUARD => 'Shooting Guard',
        self::SMALL_FORWARD => 'Small Forward',
        self::POWER_FORWARD => 'Power Forward',
        self::CENTER => 'Center'
    ];
}
```

Register BasketballPositionType for Doctrine in config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            BasketballPositionType: App\DBAL\Types\BasketballPositionType
```

Create a Player entity that has a position field:

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\DBAL\Types\BasketballPositionType;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Fresh\DoctrineEnumBundle\Validator\Constraints as DoctrineAssert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="players")
 */
class Player
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Note, that type of a field should be same as you set in Doctrine config
     * (in this case it is BasketballPositionType)
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="BasketballPositionType", nullable=false)
     * @DoctrineAssert\Enum(entity="App\DBAL\Types\BasketballPositionType")     
     */
    protected $position;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setPosition(string $position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;
    }

    public function getPosition(): string
    {
        return $this->position;
    }
}
```

Now you can set a position for Player inside some action or somewhere else:

```
$player->setPosition(BasketballPositionType::POINT_GUARD);
```

Comment: And why can't you just enforce the data type inside `setPosition` method, but instead you rely on 3rd party bundles and awful annotations?

Comment: Are you planning to implement logic in your setter method? That would not be good idea, setters and getters have to stay clear.

Comment: @SebastianViereck In my opinion, that is exactly the sort of logic that should live in getters and setters. I would argue that sort of logic is exactly why people use getters and setters.

Comment: here is a general discussions about that topic about getter and setter value manipulation: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177133/what-should-be-allowed-inside-getters-and-setters